# Datatables FixedHeader plugin in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, clojurescript

I am starting using ClojureScript, and I want to implement jQuery Datatable plugin on my site.

So far I am able to add the datatable working:

```
(:use [jayq.core :only [$]])

(if (false? (.isDataTable js/$.fn.dataTable "#report-table"))
          (def reportDatatable (.dataTable (js/$ "#report-table") (clj->js {"bProcessing" false "paging" false "searching" false "ordering" false}) ))

      )
```

The problem comes when I want to implement the FixedHeader plugin.
In http://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

The Javascript version of initializing this plugins is:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
} );
```

For some reason is not working for me the following code:

```
(.FixedHeader js/$.fn.dataTable "#report-table")
```

The error that I am getting is TypeError: Cannot set property '_oPluginFixedHeader' of undefined. I know that it is a javascript - clojurescript translation issue because If I use the console and manually execute above Javascript code it is working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So the working solution for me is:

```
(new  js/$.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader "#report-table" (clj->js {"top" true  }))
```

If someone suggests a more idiomatic way of calling a Datatable plugin, please go ahead.